# Where does the word "trivial" come from?

Tags: etymology

I have read many dictionary definitions and there seems to be two possible sources of the word *trivial*. Online [dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trivial) say it's from latin *tri* and *via*, "three ways" or "crossroad", basically meaning "street talk" or "corner talk", however [this Q&A site](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tri4.htm) states it more likely from *trivium*, which means "first three of the seven liberal arts", and strongly influenced by the former. I am not quite sure how to interpret the [etymonline.com explanation.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trivial)

Answer (score 3):

OED to the rescue again...

> Etymology:  < Latin *triviālis,* in sense **A.5** below, < *trivium* (see **trivium** *n.*); compare French *trivial* (16th cent. in Godefroy *Compl.*).

So yes, it comes **ultimately** from *trivium* = "three ways", but A.5 says

> **5.** Such as may be met with anywhere; common, commonplace, ordinary, everyday, familiar, trite. Now rare (passing into A.6).
>
> **6. a.** Of small account, little esteemed, paltry, poor; trifling, inconsiderable, unimportant, slight.

*Trivial* comes from the Latin *trivialis* which means very much what *trivial* does. Quite how the Latin *trivialis* was derived from *trivium* is beyond the scope of an English site, but it may well be to do with idle chatter on a street corner.

Comment: When a critic of *Finnegans Wake* complained that it was "trivial" to write a book in puns, Joyce replied that some of the puns were trivial, but others were quadrivial...