# Is a single factoid a trivium?

Tags: word-usage

I was writing a comment on another website, and considered introducing it with a piece of trivia. My classical education kicked into gear, and I wanted to say "Relevant trivium: ..."

I realize I could circumvent my quandary by saying "Relevant piece of trivia: ..." but now I am curious - if the dictionary.com definition of trivia is

> plural noun
>   
> 1.
>   matters or things that are very unimportant, inconsequential, or nonessential; trifles; trivialities.

Is there a place for the singular "trivium"? That word was used in the Middle Ages to indicate the first three of seven "core curriculum" subjects taught at University: grammar, logic and rhetoric. The next four subjects were arithmetic, music, geometry and astronomy (the quadrivium).

That suggests that the word is taken - but I don't know that for sure.

So at the risk of breaking the rules - here are two questions:

Can one use "trivium" to indicate a single piece of trivia? And if not, what would be the recommended alternative?

Factoid was the only one that sprang to mind. Are there any others?

Comment: You seemed to have ignored "triviality" from the definition you quoted. Will that not do?

Comment: Triviality is different.  "Factoid" is, precisely, the term to use here. But there's no reason not to make up and use another funny nonce-term.

Comment: @Margana - when I hear "triviality" I think "lack of seriousness or importance; insignificance." rather than the meaning that I am looking for (although I see now that it can be used that way).

Comment: "triviality" is different and irrelevant here.

Comment: @Floris: "lack of seriousness or importance; insignificance" - but isn't that just how the definition in your question describes "trivia", the plural of the singular you want to find? What am I missing?

Comment: @Margana - I am looking for a word meaning "a fact that is true, but the knowledge of which has no impact on your life or that of anyone else". By its nature, it can be a "heavy" fact - but without consequence. It is what one commonly calls "a piece of trivia". But this is one of those words where dictionary definitions may not fully reflect the meaning I think the word has.

Comment: *Trivial* is [derived from the Latin *trivium*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118488/where-does-the-word-trivial-come-from)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I had actually read that entry and originally intended to link it in my question - then lost my train of thought. In the original sense ("place where three roads meet") the meaning of "street corner gossip" could indeed have originated. Murky...

Comment: 'Factoid' for me is basically just a dubiously fact, it sounds cool but may or may not actually be true. A 'triviality' is something that is trivial, not (necessarily) a member of a set that is 'trivia'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question more pedantically... **trivia** is a back-formation from **trivial** (at least according to [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivia), and [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trivia) sort-of agrees).

Is **trivium** is a valid further back-formation?  Surely that depends on whether you think that **trivia** is the plural of a count noun, or a mass noun.  I agree with [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trivia), which thinks it's a mass noun, and so forming a singular out of it doesn't make complete grammatical sense.

BUT that in no sense implies it can't be used as an amusing coinage - it's every writer's right to break the rules for comic effect.  And it could in due course gain currency through use, in which case **trivia** would presumably transition to being the plural of a count noun.

PS.  Incidentally, I noticed in the process of writing this that [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/factoid) thinks a **factoid** is specifically an *unreliable* fact.  I'm not sure I quite agree that's how the word is actually used, but perhaps be careful.

Comment: Interesting. I have never associated "unreliable" with factoid. Language is a wonderful and living thing!

Comment: What happened to "factoid" is the same as what happened to "literally". By the way, the "supposed" term I have seen floating around was a "factlet".

Answer (score 2):

No.  I don't know Latin but I know a road's not a vium, but a via. Trivia derives from the intersection of three roads.  Google tells me the plural is viae.  Via is already the singular.

Comment: This is an excellent point. So although "trivia" is a plural noun, it derives from a Latin singular; as such "trivium", whilst maybe coined for humorous effect, would actually be not only pedantic but wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A "factoid" has truthiness, whereas a "fact" has truthfulness.  This is especially important in light of recent pronouncement from Washington DC. Although the euphemism du jour is now "alternate fact".  AKA, a lie.

As for "trivium", it should be obviously construed as a single item of trivia, to readers with even a modicum of knowledge of how latinate words work. (Or perhaps only to those of us those with optima, or quasi maxima of knowledge. I suspect that we amateur lexicologists are the only ones who really care about such things anyway. Consider the audience; YMMV ).

By comparison: "agenda", a plural, is now generally construed as a singular noun, with a typical plural of "agendas" (or sometimes, "agenda".)  "Agendum", though rarely used, is clearly (to us) one item on an agenda, but is now dually defined, at least in one dictionary, with the primary meaning of "agenda".  That is, the singular "agendum" is equated with the singular "agenda", which has a plural of either "agenda" or "agendas".
(see http://www.dictionary.com/browse/agendum )
Would it be better to coin "agendoid"?  Or "agendicule"?  Or "trivicule"? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only answer here is: it would indeed read on the page as you coining a word in a funny way.

{Much as a couple of Doods might add "-age" on the end of stuff .. "Time for some beerage, dude?!"}

> Can one use "trivium" to indicate a single piece of trivia?

Yes, for sure.  The fact that "trivium" was a very obscure word one thousand years ago - is in my opinion totally irrelevant.

You're simply making-up another funny alternative to "factoid". Sounds great to me.

(This is like one of those intellectual discussions comedy writers have about something funny :) )

Comment: I appreciate your inputs - good to hear that (to you at least) it comes across as funny rather than pedantic. I'll wait and see what others think/say.

Comment: now that's subtle!  :)  just a typo.  For sure, let's see if it gets some laffs. I actually think it's great. I'm gonna use it all the time now.  It's stuck already see? :)  This new word you coined has become like one of those relationships you talk about before it even happens!